# Postgres database "information_schema" in JPA

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa

I've created project using Postgres database. Tables are created in information_schema, that's why I need to add schema argument `@Table` or `@JoinTable`, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book",  schema = "information_schema")
public class Book { ...
```

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(
    name = "book_genre",
    schema = "information_schema",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "book_id"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id"))
private List<Genre> genres = new ArrayList<>();
```

What setting should I change to avoid this? Maybe I should set it in settings of my application?
`application.yml` looks like this:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres"
    username: ...
    password: ...
```

Comment: @ScaryWombat It is not the schema, it is the database (a.k.a. catalog in JDBC terminology)

Answer (score 1):

```
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      schema: ${database.schema}
  liquibase:
    default-schema: ${database.schema}
  jpa:
    properties:
      hibernate:
        default_schema: ${database.schema}
```